# Differentiate between multiple instances of same program

Tags: bots, autoit, pid

How to target processes by PID? I have multiple instances of the same program active at the same time, but my code only works for one. I want to target all instances.

So where to put the PID (I mean the first line) or how else to differentiate between multiple instances?

```
Global $WindowTitle = "World of Warcraft"

Global $PauseKey = "{F7}"
Global $TerminateKey = "{F8}"
Global $PVPOpenKey = "{h}"
Global $MacroBindKey = "{8}{a}"

Global $Paused = False

HotKeySet( $PauseKey, "Pause" )
HotKeySet( $TerminateKey, "Terminate" )

While 1
    If Not $Paused Then
        ControlSend( $WindowTitle, "", 0, $PVPOpenKey )
        Sleep( 5000 )
        ControlSend( $WindowTitle, "", 0, $MacroBindKey )
    EndIf

    Sleep( 500 )
WEnd

Func Pause()
    $Paused = Not $Paused
EndFunc

Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to get all the PIDs for certain processes you can use [`ProcessList()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ProcessList.htm).

```
; List PIDs for wow.exe processes
$list = ProcessList("wow.exe")
For $i = 1 To $list[0][0]
    MsgBox(0, "Hi!", $list[$i][1])
Next
```